# Как вывести на втором активити результат?

Tags: java, activity, android, android-asynctask

```
 class findgroup extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String groupName = group.getText().toString(); // приводим к типу String
    private int i = 0;
    private boolean bool=false;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        do {
            if(groupName.equals(SpisokGrp[i])){
                bool=true;
            }
            else{
                i++;
            }
        } while (false);
        groupName = SpisokGrp[i];
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        rasp.setText(groupName);
    }
}
```

Это описано у меня в отдельном файле класса для первого активити, где должен идти поиск, на втором активити выводиться результат поиска. 
Вот такой массив, по которому идет поиск:

```
private String[] SpisokGrp = {"ip-203", "ip-204"};
```

Последняя строчка по сути должна выводить итог во втором активити, то есть "ip-204". Подскажите, я новичок, первую неделю только за андройдом сижу. Я AsyncTask  неправильно использую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас AsynkTask находится в отдельном классе от Activity, вы сначала должны вернуть ей результат c помощью слушателя. Если он реализован в Activity тогда сразу можете положить массив в Intent и запустить вторую Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("spisok_tag", SpisokGrp);
startActivity(intent);
```

После во второй Activity достаете массив:

```
String[] SpisokGrp = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("spisok_tag");
```

Comment: а можно ли использовать AsyncTask в обеих Activity?

Comment: А зачем? Если вам результат нужен только во второй Activity, там его и запускайте, если и в первой, то запускайте и получайте результат в первой и передавайте во вторую. Если же вы не знаете в каком Activity будете находится во время загрузки данных используйте Service.